# Matlab `parfor` for simple kinematic calculations

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, physics

I will use this simple made-up, self-contained function, which is supposed to get as inputs: the initial position, force, time step and number of iterations; and return as outputs: the time and position vectors.

```
function [time,pos] = example(pos0, force, N, dt) 

clc;

pos = zeros(N+1,3);
vel = zeros(N,3);
pos(1,:)=pos0;


for i = 1:N

        time(i+1) = i*dt;

        % solver finds the velocities given forces and previous positions
        vel(i,:) = force./(norm(pos(i,:)+1));

        % evolution calculates new positions using new velocities
        pos(i+1,:) = pos(i,:) + vel(i,:)*dt;

end

end
```

I would like to compute this using the parellel pool - in my case consisting of 2 cores. The modified code below does not work, because of the way the variable `pos` is used, which makes it so that each iteration depends on the previous one. How could I fix it? I have read the documentation, but it is quite obscure to me, even for this simple cases. Is it possible to parallelise this at all?

```
function [time,pos] = example(pos0, force, N, dt) 

clc;
delete(gcp('nocreate'));

pos = zeros(N+1,3);
vel = zeros(N,3);
pos(1,:)=pos0;

parpool(2)

parfor i = 1:N

        time(i+1) = i*dt;

        % solver finds the velocities given forces and previous positions
        vel(i,:) = force./(norm(pos(i,:)+1));

        % evolution calculates new positions using new velocities
        pos(i+1,:) = pos(i,:) + vel(i,:)*dt;

end

end
```

Comment: You can do it only for independent iterations. Not for dependent iterations

Comment: The parfor loop from MatLab documentation: "The body of the parfor-loop is executed in a parallel pool using multiple MATLAB workers in a nondeterministic order." In your code you have written: "solver finds the velocities given forces and previous positions". Therefore you need a deterministic approach, where each position is computed depending on the previous.

Comment: Could I use `parfeval` for this then?